# Unable pull out the node value of src using getattribute

Tags: php

I am trying to echo out the `href` and the image `src` using `getattribute` but though the `href` gets echoed correctly I am unable to retrieve the image src...plz guide. below is my

**html mockup**

```
<div id="hot-deals">
  <div class="all-deals">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://url1.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink1.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://url2.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink2.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://url3.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink3.com"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my code**

```
$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//div[@id="hot-deals"]/div[@class="all-deals"]/ul/li/a' );
foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {    
      $title=$node->getAttribute('href');
      $img=$node->getAttribute('img/src');
      echo $title.",".$img."<br>";  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`src` is not attribute of `a` tag, so you need one more step to get inner `img` tag and then take its attribute

```
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {   
  $title = $node->getAttribute('href');
  $imgTags = $node->getElementsByTagName('img');
  $img = $imgTags->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
  echo $title . "," . $img . "<br>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
<?php
$str = '<div id="hot-deals">
  <div class="all-deals">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://url1.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink1.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://url2.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink2.com"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://url3.com">
          <img src="http://imagelink3.com"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>';

$nodes = simplexml_import_dom(DOMDocument::loadHTML($str))->xpath('//div[@id="hot-deals"]/div[@class="all-deals"]/ul/li/a');


foreach( $nodes as $node )
{   
  $title = $node['href'];
  $src = $node->img['src'];
  echo $title ." " . $src . '<br>';  
}
```